# is there a way to set the default value of a v-select to an entire table

Tags: vue.js

I have a v-select component that allows the user to select multiple items. I have a select all that when the user click on it will send 'All' to the api and would select all the items.
Is there a way to make the select all as the default option.

Comment: You can just treat null/empty selection the same as "All" when the API method is called. e.g. `if (selection.includes("All") || selection.length === 0) { sendAPIcall() }`  if you provide some code showing how your v-select / API call works I could provide a more official answer.  it would also be helpful to include what version of vue + vuetify you're using.

Comment: I am using vue 2, I don't have a problem with the API call , I need to be able to check all the checkboxes when the user 'select all' ' <v-select 
                                          :items='[{text: "Select All", value:"All"}, ...myItem]'
                                          v-model="selectedItem"
                                          multiple
                                           > </v-select> I need when the user select 'All' to check all myItems in the v-select

Comment: If that's the problem, then you would add an event listener on the v-select that runs a method either on `@click` or `@change` (see the [docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#events)).  the method checks if the option just selected is "all", and if true, sets the v-model with all options.

Comment: Ok I get it but I am stuck with setting the v-model to all the options part don't know how to do it

Comment: there's actually an example in the [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#append-and-prepend-item) on how to do exactly this

Comment: I used this example to do the multi select but my problem still I have to click select all , I need to have select all as a default and have all the items selected if it is clicked

Comment: What does "as a default" mean exactly?  Or rather, what does the "select all" example in the Vuetify docs fail at providing you?  by my understanding you require an option labeled "select all" that when clicked, selects every option available.  That is what I see provided in the Vuetify docs already, specifically the section that goes over using the ["prepend-item" slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#append-and-prepend-item), so I don't know what else is needed. Sorry that I don't understand :(

Comment: No worries sorry for the poor explanation, what vuetify has is what I implemented but what I need is to have the 'Select all' already selected once the user starts the app so s/he can see all the data for all the items

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the issue now: to have "Select All" option (and by consequence, all options) selected when the page loads.

All the "Select All" option does is toggle the `v-model` having all the items, or none of the items. To have "Select All" selected on page load simply requires that the `v-model` have all `items` assigned to it as it's initial value.

Using the example code from the [Vuetify docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#append-and-prepend-item)

```html
<v-select v-model="selectedFruits" :items="fruits" multiple>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  fruits: ['Apples', 'Apricots', 'Avocado', 'Bananas'],
  selectedFruits: ['Apples', 'Apricots', 'Avocado', 'Bananas']
})
```

Or, alternatively

```js
data: () => ({
  fruits: ['Apples', 'Apricots', 'Avocado', 'Bananas'],
  selectedFruits: []
}),
mounted() {
  this.selectedFruits = this.fruits.slice()
}
```

[working sandbox example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)